# Tomcat: War file deploys locally but on online server gets a 404

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, centos

Running `java 1.7`...mockbuild 
Installed via

```
  $ yum install java
```

on `centOS 6.6`

Used gradle assemble to build the war file.
Deployed it locally with `Tomcat`.
Secure copied it over to `centOS`.
Deployed it.

Get a 404 when navigating to the webapp homepage.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a weird version of Java. Try to

$ yum remove java

$ yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk